# Is there a function that will ignore capital letters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, case-insensitive, capitalization

i have a chatbot that answers questions only if i write them the same way as in the code Ex: If i wrote the tag "Hello" it will not answer if i say in the chatbot "hello" . I have to write it with a capital letter like in the code. Is there a function that will ignore that and answer it even if i write it "HeLlO"?

```
if (message.indexOf("Bye")>=0 || message.indexOf("bye")>=0 ||  message.indexOf("Goodbye")>=0  ||  message.indexOf("Goodbye")>=0  ){
    send_message("You're welcome.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression in case-insensitive mode:

```
if (/bye/i.test(message)) {
    send_message("You're welcome.");
}
```

Also, there's no need to test for both `bye` and `goodbye` -- if it contains `goodbye` then it obviously also contains `bye`.

But if you want to test for different messages, the regexp also makes this easy:

```
if (/bye|adios|arrivederci/i.test(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `message.toLowerCase()` to convert uppercase letters to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `toLowerCase` method to do the trick.

Example:

```
msg = "HeLlo"
msg.toLowerCase() // "hello"
msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("hello")>=0 // true
```

Or you can make use of the String prototype to create a case-insensitive `contains` method:

```
String.prototype.ci_contains = function(str){
    return this.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
}
```

Use Example:

```
msg = "ByE"
msg.ci_contains("bye") // True
msg.ci_contains("Bye") // True
```

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to use the:

- .toLowerCase()

This helps to compair without case sensitive i.e:

```
  function compairWithNoCase(valueCompair1,valueCompair2)
    {
        return valueCompair1.toLowerCase().match(
                                         valueCompair2.toLowerCase()
                                                )==valueCompair1.toLowerCase()
    }
/*
compairWithNoCase('hElLo','HeLlO');
true
compairWithNoCase('BYE','HELLO');
false
compairWithNoCase('ByE','bYe');
true
*/
```